# rule-based agent or utility-based agent

Tags: agent, agents-jade, multi-agent

I am going to develop an agent system using JADE to handle dynamic situations in selecting optimal electric vehicle charging station by the electric vehicle owner. To simulate this system, which agent can successfully handle dynamic situations, rule-based agent or utility-based agent?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the jessAgent in jade/src/examples/jess. It is a agent that embeds a jess engine, which is a rule-based expert system. Relate to http://herzberg.ca.sandia.gov/jess .